# Can I change the animate property of a canvas source in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

When adding a [canvas source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#canvassource) to a mapbox-gl-js map, there is an [animate option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-canvas-animate). Some of the canvases that I'm working with are rather large and static MOST of the time. To improve performance I would like to toggle the animate property on and off at will. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, canvas sources have `play` and `pause` methods:

```
const source = map.getSource('mySource');
source.pause();
source.play();
```

Comment: This wasn't documented before but is now ticketed at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5085 :)

Comment: Thanks so much Lauren.